# In Xcode 6, how do I delete a view and the memory associated with it?

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-management, swift

I am creating thousands of views in swift on Xcode 6 in an osx app, but I only want maybe a hundred to exist at a time so that it isn't taking up tons of memory. All I want is the equivalent of this:

```
    myview = NSView()
    <some code goes here working with myview>
    myview.dealloc()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a local variable, you don't need to do anything in particular; just allow the variable to go out of scope, and the runtime will automatically clean it up for you.

The tricky part comes in when you have other objects which may have a reference to the view.  In that case, you'll need to clear out all possible references to the view so that the system can reclaim the object.  Usually, this means setting any references to `nil`, but if you've put them in an array, you'll need to remove them.  If you've added them to another view, you'll need to take remove them from there as well.